# trouble reading variables in an array of reference java

Tags: java

i am reading from a csv file that reads a country name and takes a subscription data  for a particular country at a certain year. Below is a csv sample file:

```
CountryName,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012
Aruba,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.029310471,0,0,2.138784453,3.605985937,3.98141538,6.16435217,13.48254011,16.50927821,57.05427692,65.05605558,72.10431377,99.64250268,103.3849507,108.1325002,112.2180618,119.2038996,126.2103374,129.72824,0,131.8565401               
Andorra,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.307211734,1.278625641,1.250259142,4.424155104,8.538444783,13.44671556,22.12730607,32.14530928,35.99902139,43.27794118,45.77115817,68.60251444,73.82494308,79.48487497,84.27763597,78.1171579,80.2836099,82.06181111,84.06818386,83.53432222,81.50204186                         
Afghanistan,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.112598381,0.865196277,2.498055472,4.826865367,9.833164022,17.71624331,29.22037376,37.89493697,45.77817474,60.32631999,60.35299258
```

I am able to read the file fine. I created 2 classes. 1 class called `class subscriptionYear` that reads the year that i called `int year`, and variable `double subscription` that reads each stats data. 2nd class called `Class Country`. It reads the country called `String countryNames` and a 1d array called `SubscriptionYear[] subscriptions` which holds all the subscription data for that country. I have 2 methods in class country called `addSubscriptionYear(int year, double countryData)` which reads the data  I am to follow the guideline of the test class called `class TestCountry`. My program reads the file but outputting the wrong sum. Basically it reads only 2012 and not the entire period between 1960 and 2012. so when i do the sum it is only outputs the stats of 2012 and not the entire sum of from 1960 to 2012. My problem seems to be from `addSubscriptionYear method` which inserts the year and data into the `class Subscription` but it only reads the year 2012 and not the entire period from 1960 to 2012 when i tried debugging it. I have to follow the guidelines from `TestCountry class` as this is the requirement. But my function method `addSubscriptionYear()` is the problem. Could some one please help me out or some tips how to store each year and data in the array of objects. Below is my file

class Subscription:

```
public class SubscriptionYear {

private int year;
private double subscriptions;

public SubscriptionYear(int year,double subscriptions)
{
    //this.year = year;
    //this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    setYear(year);
    setSubscription(subscriptions);
}
public void setYear(int Year)
{
    this.year= Year;
}
public void setSubscription(double value)
{
    this.subscriptions = value;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}
public double getSubscription()
{
    return subscriptions;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Number of Subscriptions: "+subscriptions;
}
}
```

class Country:

```
public class Country {

private String countryNames;
private SubscriptionYear[] subscriptions;
private int size;

public Country(String country, int arraylength)
{
    this.countryNames = country;
    this.size = arraylength;
    subscriptions = new SubscriptionYear[size];
}
 //seems to be where i am having the problem
 //only reads 2012 and not 1960. seems to be my problem
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
    for(int i=0;i<subscriptions.length;i++)
    {
        subscriptions[i]= new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
    }
        //System.out.print(subscriptions[0].getYear()+"\t");

}
public double getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod(int start, int end)
{
    double sum = 0;
    int head = subscriptions[0].getYear()-start;
    int tail = end-start;
    if(head>=0&&end<subscriptions.length)/check if out of bounds.
    {
    for(int k=head;k<=tail;k++)
    {
        sum += subscriptions[k].getSubscription();
    }
   } else{ sum =-1;}
   return sum;
}
public String toString()
{
    System.out.print(countryNames+"\t");
    for(SubscriptionYear s: subscriptions)
    {
        //System.out.print(countryNames+"\t");
        System.out.print(s.getSubscription()+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
    return  "";
}
}
```

Tesfile:

```
/**
 *  Tests the Country class by creating multiple objects.
 *  Creates one object of type CSVReader class, which reads input from a CSV file. Uses
 *  the attributes stored in CSVReader object to create objects of type Country class.
 */
public class TestCountry 
{

/**
 * Includes test examples for class Country.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Create and set objects of type Country 
    //
    final String FILENAME = "data/cellular.csv";    // Directory path for Mac OS X
    //final String FILENAME = "data\cellular.csv";  // Directory path for Windows OS (i.e. Operating System)
    final int NUM_COUNTRIES_TO_TEST = 3;            // Note: Include test cases in addition to 3


    // Parse the CSV data file
    //
    CSVReader parser = new CSVReader(FILENAME);

    String [] countryNames = parser.getCountryNames();
    int [] yearLabels = parser.getYearLabels();
    double [][] parsedTable = parser.getParsedTable();      


    // Create and set objects of type Country 
    //
    Country [] countries;
    //countries = new Country[NUM_COUNTRIES_TO_TEST];   // Note: Use this for initial testing of your implementation.
    countries = new Country[countryNames.length];                

    Country current;

    for (int countryIndex = 0; countryIndex < countries.length; countryIndex++)
    {
        int numberOfYears = yearLabels.length;   // OR numberOfYears = dataTable[countryIndex].length;

        current = new Country(countryNames[countryIndex], numberOfYears);

        for (int yearIndex = 0; yearIndex < numberOfYears; yearIndex++)
        {
            double [] allSubscriptions = parsedTable[countryIndex];
            double countryData = allSubscriptions[yearIndex];
            current.addSubscriptionYear(yearLabels[yearIndex], countryData);
        }
        countries[countryIndex] = current;
    }
        //for(int i =0;i<countries.length;i++)
        //{
    //System.out.print(countries[8]);
        //}
        //System.out.println();
    System.out.printf(countryNames[0] + " (1960 to 2012): %.2f \n", countries[0].getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod(1960,2012));
    // the output is 131.63 and should be 1170.50 

    System.out.printf(countryNames[100] + " (1960 to 2012): %.2f \n", countries[100].getNumSubscriptionsForPeriod(1960,2012));
    // the output is 112.67 and should be 1246.58 
}
 }
```

It outputs 131.63 for aruba and not 1170.50. It basically only reads stats for 2012 and not entire period of 1960 to 2012. I need help on fixing addSubscriptionYear method in class Country.

Comment: Where is code for getCountryNames() getYearLabels() and getParsedTable().

Comment: @brso05 posted the code u asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only keeping the last date, because you put a for loop in the `addSubscriptionYear()` method and that is overriding all the previous values, so remove the for loop, and keep track of your current index in the table by adding and int to your class `Country` that will increment every time you call the method `addSubscriptionYear()`

```
int lastPos = 0;
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
    subscriptions[lastPos]= new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
    lastPos++;
}
```

Comment: brso05 asked for the code. But did you try the solution I have proposed?

Comment: here you go I have added it

Comment: because every time you were adding the same value in the entire list. but what you should do is adding the SubscriptionYear only in the last place in the list